# Facebook API v6.0 to find mutual friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends, mutual-friendship

With the most recent version (6.0) of the Facebook Graph API, there are no longer endpoints to find mutual friends between two users or get the friends list of a user.

If I want to find the number of mutual friends of two users on my app, how would I go about doing so? I can get the number of mutual friends who are also using the app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/friends/), but what if I want to get the total number of mutual friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t do that any more.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version3.1#mutual-friends-api:

> Mutual Friends API
> These changes apply to v3.1+, and will apply to all versions on October 24, 2018.
>
> The Mutual Friends API was deprecated on April 4, 2018, and the endpoints below started returning empty data sets. The endpoints are now fully deprecated and will return an error.
>
> /user-context/all_mutual_friends
> /user-context/mutual_friends
> /user-context/three_degree_mutual_friends

This has been removed for good, and there is no current replacement.